# Why "des" in "il y a des petits morceaux de légumes"?

Tags: articles, de, déterminants

I have learned that when you have a structure like "des adjective noun" the "des" becomes "de". But a Duolingo sentence seems to contradict this. I have tried really hard but failed to find an explanation. Why is it "il y a **des** petits morceaux de légumes" not "il y a **de** petits morceaux de légumes"?

Also this seems to be a separate issue but if I'm talking about some specific vegetables can I also use "des" with légumes and say "des petits morceaux des légumes"? I know it likely changes the meaning a little but would it work?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The "de vs des" question has been answered quite a lot on here already, but in your particular case, this sentence is correct and *could* be accepted by Duolingo:

> il y a de petits morceaux de légumes

But you wrote :

> il y a de petits morceaux **des** légumes

and that's incorrect, you can't use *des* before *légumes* here, not if you used *de* before.

> il y a *des* petits morceaux **des** légumes

Although rare, this sentence could work technically, it means "there are little pieces of *the* vegetables" and implies you've mentioned those vegetables before and you're talking about what happened to them. It doesn't make much sense in this sentence but grammatically it's possible to have a sentence like this.

---

More importantly, it's a "Tap what you hear" exercise so there's no room for "slighty different but also correct sentence" that could be accepted in a translation exercise. You're supposed to input exactly what was said.